# Need Help in converting Classic ASP Code to ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net

```
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", "http://www.indexguy.com/request_server.cfm?member_id=15893&id="+request.querystring("id")+"&"+request.querystring, False
xml.Send
```

How can I build the querystring parameter to a string object in C#/VB.NET

```
"member_id=15893&id="+request.querystring("id")+"&"+request.querystring"
```

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET, you're going to want to replace the `Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` with `HttpWebRequest`.

As for building the query string, that's still identical. You can still retrieve query string parameters by indexing into `Request.QueryString`. If you're using C# you can keep the `+` for string concatenation but might be more acceptable to use `&` in VB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to build a querystring, `String.Format("{0}", arg)` might be a cleaner method to construct it.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET the [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class exposes a [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) property which provides access to a [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) property - this is a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) that lets you get values out in much the same way as in your existing example, by specifying keys:

```
var id = Page.Request.QueryString("id");

var newQuery = string.Format("?member_id=15893&id={0}&", id);
```

The above can easily be expanded to build more into your required query string.

As for the request you're initiating, that can be achieved using a [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) instance; to alter the sample from MSDN only slightly, here is an example:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(yourUrl + newQuery);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();   
Response.Write(response.StatusDescription);

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Response.Write(responseFromServer);

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```